# Bind function to the event "onclick" of the elements of an array of buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

Preamble: I'm Italian, sorry for my bad English.

This is my problem:

I want to assign a function to a set of buttons.

I need to send a parameter to the function.

this is the code that I've tried:

```
function test(atxt) {
    var buttons = $('.tblButton');

    for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].onClick(sayHello(atxt));
    }
}

function sayHello(txt){alert('hello' + txt)};
```

...getting the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLButtonElement> has no method 'onClick'
```

can you tell me where I went wrong and how can I fix it?

EDIT: I need iteration because I need the 'id of the button as a parameter of the function so i need to do `buttons[i].onClick(sayHello(buttons[i].id))`

Comment: Why aren't you just using $('.tblButton').click(...)?

Comment: I need iteration because I need the 'id of the button as a parameter of the function so i need to do buttons[i].onClick(sayHello(buttons[i].id))

Comment: But you could just use sayHello($(this).attr('id')) - inside the above code

Comment: you mean something like: `$('.tblButton').onClick(function(){sayHello($(this).attr('id'))} )` ??

Comment: $('.tblButton').on('click', function(){ sayHello($(this).attr('id')); });

Comment: See my last example for the id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this not work for your example: Do you have another reason for the iteration?

```
function test(atxt) {
    $('.tblButton').on('click',function(){sayHello(atxt);});
}

function sayHello(txt){alert('hello' + txt)};
```

OR optionally if the elements are static and present:

```
function test(atxt) {
    $('.tblButton').click(function(){sayHello(atxt);});
}

function sayHello(txt){alert('hello' + txt)};
```

Alternate approach: just change
to this style:

```
var txt = "fred";
var atext = "hello" + txt;

function sayHello(atext) {
    alert(atext);
}
$('.tblButton').on('click', function() {
    sayHello(atext);
});
//below here just to demonstrate
$('.tblButton').eq(0).click();//fires with the fred
txt = "Johnny";// new text
atext = 'hello' + txt;
$('.tblButton').eq(1).click();//fires the Johnny
```

see it working here:
http://jsfiddle.net/dFBMm/

SO based on your note:
this markup and code:

```
<button class="tblButton" id="Ruth">Hi</button>
<button class="tblButton" id="Betty">Hi again</button>

$('.tblButton').on('click', function() {
    alert("Hello "+$(this).attr("id"));
});
$('.tblButton').eq(0).click();//fires with the Ruth
$('.tblButton').eq(1).click();//fires the Betty
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dFBMm/1/

Comment: I need iteration because I need the 'id of the button as a parameter of the function so i need to do buttons[i].onClick(sayHello(buttons[i].id))

Comment: you don't need that you can use `$(this).attr('id')` or similar

Answer (score 5):

```
buttons[i].onClick(sayHello(atxt));
```

Supposed to be

```
$(buttons[i]).on('click', function() { sayHello(atxt) });
```

If you want to get the **current button id** then I think you are looking for this..

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
     $(buttons[i]).on('click', function() { sayHello(this.id) });
}
```

Comment: `buttons[i]` is a DOM node, not a jQuery object.

Comment: @JanDvorak .. Over looked that .. Thanks :)

Comment: Note that "attaching to a class" indicates a "live" behavior, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to iterate through all of the buttons then you have to do that with `.each()` handler of the jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $(".tblButton").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function(){
       alert($(this).attr('id'));
    }); 
  });
});
```

checkout the jsbin: **http://jsbin.com/usideg/1/edit**