# JQuery binding click event on HTMLButtonElement

Tags: jquery, button, bind

So I have an array of buttons and when I try to assign for each one a click event like this
`button[i].bind("click", function() ...`  it says the Object #  has no method "bind".

What can be the problem ?

Comment: Could you post a small snippet of the code?  You may not need to iterate over an array.

Comment: You can try this



  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883225/bind-function-to-the-event-onclick-of-the-elements-of-an-array-of-buttons

Answer (score 1):

you should try

```
$(button[i]).on("click", function(){});
```

`button[i]` is a javascript object so you need to convert it in jQuery object by using `$(button[i])` to apply jquery events.

Answer (score 1):

`button[i]` isn't a jquery object, so it doesn't have `bind` function.

You're not showing enough code for me to give you the full solution but you should end up with

```
$(button[i]).bind("click", function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

The array "button" probably contains selectors (strings like "#xyz"), not objects. You need to convert them to objects:

```
$(button[i]).bind("click", function()
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following HTML:

```
<button>Something</button>
<button>Something</button>
<button>Something</button>
```

You can obtain the array of buttons as follows:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
```

Then just pass the entire array to jQuery to bind the buttons:

```
$(buttons).click(function(){
   alert("hello");
});
```

Or just select all the buttons to start with:

```
$("button").click(function(){
   alert("hello");
});
```

The main point I'm trying to convey is that you most likely do not need to iterate over the button [] with `.forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

if these buttons exist within a common ancestor it would be more performant to bind the click on that parent element.

```
$('.parent').on('click','button',function(e){
   ...
});
```

If these buttons have a common function then that makes life easier - if there is are different behaviours required for each function then look to use a data attribut on the button where you could specify a different method to execute for each.